# Save certain fileds in a Caldera form to a separate wordpress table

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm looking to save certain fileds in a Caldera form to a separate wordpress table when I submit the form, is this possible? Fields that are needed are standard, First name, surname, address, postcode etc.

The wordpress table (client_list) is setup with the same fields, First name, surname, address, postcode etc.

Just need a bit of help if possible
Tony

Comment: There are likely some filter/action hooks already provided by the plugin that you could use for this. Have you checked [Caldera Form's documentation](https://calderaforms.com/caldera-forms-documentation-2/) yet?

Comment: Yeah, been trying to get my head around it this afternoon with no sucess.